# If I change the value of a variable in one function, will the changed value be used in another in Java?

Tags: java, function, variables, methods

```
d=1;
public void method1()
{
    d+=1;
}
public void method2()
{
    if(d==1)
System.out.println(d);
}
```

Will the variable's value be carried over to the other method? If not, how can we make sure it is?

Comment: Try it your self first. 
hints: you can look into access modifiers and scope. If  you still have a problem do let us know.

Comment: It depends. Where is the rest of your source? See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: what type of variable `d` is? is it instance variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If d is the instance variable then it would be visibile to every method that you defined above.

Answer (score 0):

Having `d=1;` outside any method won't compile.

If `d` is an instance variable, you can declare it as `int d=1;`

In that case, any non-static method can update it and see the updated value.